# .on('stream') event doesn't seem to fire using peerjs + react-native-peerjs

Tags: react-native, electron, webrtc, peerjs

I'm trying to connect my laptop and mobile using [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/docs.html)

I kick off the electron app on my laptop first, generate an ID and pass that to my react native app, which then attempts to connect on a press of a button.

**Desktop**

```
const webPeer = new Peer({host: ip, port: 8090, path: '/peer', debug: 2});
    var webId;

    webPeer.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("I NEVER SEE THIS", error);
    });

    webPeer.on('open', async (id) => {
        // I pass this to the phone here - works fine and I see the console log on the line below
        console.log("Saved Web ID", webId);

        webPeer.on('call', function(call) {
            console.log("Getting call from mobile");
            call.answer(stream);    
        });
    }); // I Never get any messages in the console for disconnected or 'close' events

    webPeer.on('disconnected', function() {
        console.log('Disconnection on web...');
        // update app to show disconnected error
    });

    webPeer.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Closing...');
        // update app to show disconnected error
    });
```

**Mobile**

```
const mobPeer = new Peer({
      host: ipv4, secure: false, port: 8090, path: '/peer', debug: 1
    });

    mobPeer.connect(webId);

    mobPeer.on('open', function(id) {
      // I see this in the console
      console.log('Mobile id is', id);
    });

    // I never see any of the below events appear in the console

    mobPeer.on('call', function(call) {
      console.log("Got remote stream", call);
      call.answer(null);
    });

    mobPeer.on('disconnected', function() {
      console.log('Disconnection on web...');
      // update app to show disconnected error
    });

    mobPeer.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Closing...');
        // update app to show disconnected error
    });
```

When I try to connect => call => answer, I get this in the console of the electron/desktop app:

`Connected
Connected
OFFER from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
CANDIDATE from r7a3vxg2q4000000 to qre0pfj8zin00000
[20580:0116/033646.215:ERROR:audio_rtp_receiver.cc(88)] AudioRtpReceiver::OnSetVolume: No audio channel exists.
ANSWER from qre0pfj8zin00000 to r7a3vxg2q4000000
CANDIDATE from qre0pfj8zin00000 to r7a3vxg2q4000000
ERROR PeerServer:  Message unrecognized
ERROR PeerServer:  Message unrecognized
ERROR PeerServer:  Message unrecognized
ERROR PeerServer:  Message unrecognized
ERROR PeerServer:  Message unrecognized`

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i have the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: Hi @jones, despite the useless comments from the other guy, I did get somewhere with it. It's been a while so I can't really remember what I did, though. I remember having an issue with the react-native-peerjs package that was fixed with a new update at the time.